# Rails, how to do a custom active record join that doesn't use ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have two models *Users* and *Friendships* in my RoR application

The *friendships* table contains two integer fields *user1* and *user2*, both these fields represent a relationship.

How would I go about selecting all friends for a given user id that exists in either the *user1* or *user2* field?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `find_by_sql`

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/find_by_sql/class

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at ActiveRecord's [has_many](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many) method documentation. I think you may be able to do something like:

```
class User
  has_many :friendships, :finder_sql => lambda { |user| ["SELECT * FROM friendships WHERE user1 = :id OR user2 = :id", :id => user.id] }

  def friends
    ids = friendships.map(&:user1) + friendships.map(&:user2)
    ids.uniq!
    ids.delete(id)
    User.find(ids)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class User
  def friends
    user_ids = Friendship.where(["user1 = :id OR user2 = :id", :id => self.id]).inject([]) {|sum,x| sum << x.user1 && sum << x.user2 }.uniq-[self.id]
    User.find(user_ids)
  end
end
```